# Shrinkwrapped image shows edges of transparent background

Tags: edges, shrinkwrap

[image: Element 3D Screenshot]

I brought my blender created model into Element 3D within After Effects. In Blender and Element 3D everything looks good but when I go back to my timeline and view I can see the edges of the Shrinkwrapped images on the model's face. Anyone have some troubleshooting suggestions for this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I figured this out! You have to go into Element 3D's Scene Setup, select the image that's shrinkwrapped onto the object, scroll down in the Edit window to the Advanced section and change AO Mode to Receive RTAO. Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.